# Android FileInputStream/FileOutputStream inaccessible after reboot, before unlock

Tags: android

I have a background service which is started after a reboot by a receiver which gets the ACTION_LOCK_BOOT_COMPLETED intent, and the service is started and running as expected after reboot, before the screen is unlocked.

However, in this service, I need to access files in external storage, via FileInputStream and FileOutputStream. After the screen is unlocked, all of this works as expected, so I know the implementation is correct and the app has all the appropriate permissions, i.e. I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, before the screen is unlocked, the files cannot be accessed, and I get:

W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /data/user/0/{path}/files: mkdir failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/data/{path}/files): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Is there some limitation that external storage cannot be accessed before the screen is unlocked, and if so, is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/direct-boot.html#run).

The problem was due to the fact that in Direct Boot mode (before the screen is unlocked), I need to use a device protected storage context instead of the regular context, as suggested in the article.

```
Context directBootContext = appContext.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext();
// Access appDataFilename that lives in device encrypted storage
FileInputStream inStream = directBootContext.openFileInput(appDataFilename);
// Use inStream to read content...
```

After doing this, I was able to access files even before the screen is unlocked.